# Tuple declaration goes to infinite loop

Tags: haskell, tuples, infinite-loop

Trying this in Prelude

```
Prelude> (i, j) = (3, 4)
Prelude> (i, j) = (j, i)
Prelude> i
```

I was expecting `4`, but I get an infinite loop

Why ?

How to do this in a short elegant way ?

Comment: It has nothing to do with lazy evaluation (itself). You simply created cyclic references: `i` points to `j`, and `j` points to `i`. The first statement has no impact whatsoever, since in Haskell variables can not change, you constructed new ones.

Comment: Thanks, but why is `i` and `j` not referring to 3 and 4 then ? (in the second line)

Comment: Because as said before, from the moment you write something like `(i,j) = (j,i)` there are variables that occur in the head, and these are locally scoped. So you created *new* variables `i` and `j`. So the first line has no impact at all.

Comment: In Haskell, the `=` is *not* an assignment operator, it is a *declaration*.

Comment: I never talked about assignment, I am indeed talking about declaration of new variable with same name as old ones.
I did not know that variables that occur in the head are locally scoped ! thanks

Comment: It doesn't. We could easily define a similar, but  strict, language with the same scoping.

Comment: Ok I edited my question thanks ! Then it has to do with recursivity ?

Comment: If you define `factorial n = if n == 0 then 1 else n * (factorial (n - 1))`, you expect the use of `factorial` on the RHS to be the same `factorial` as the one on the LHS, right? Well in the same way, `(i,j) = (j,i)` defines `i` and `j` in terms of themselves.

Comment: Thanks ! That's the answer I was looking for. If you post it as an answer, I will accept it

Comment: If you really aren't looking for assignment, then you could give the new variables new names to avoid the problem: `(i2, j2) = (j, i)`. That probably isn't super useful though, so we might need more context.

Comment: What if I want to keep the same variable names as the old ones ? Is there a way ?

Comment: What exactly did you expect to receive when you did `Prelude> i`..?

Comment: If you’re in `do` notation, you can shadow variables with a monadic binding, because unlike `let` bindings, they’re non-recursive: `do { let { (i, j) = (3, 4) }; (i, j) <- pure (j, i); print i; print j }` prints `4` then `3` because this desugars to `let (i, j) = (3, 4) in pure (j, i) >>= \ (i, j) -> print i >> print j`, and the `i` and `j` parameters of the inner lambda shadow those defined by the outer `let`. (You can also get recursive bindings in `do` blocks using the `RecursiveDo` extension; writing `rec (j, i) <- (i, j)` will enter an infinite loop just like `let (j, i) = (i, j)` does.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you define

```
ghci> factorial n = if n == 0 then 1 else n * (factorial (n - 1))
```

you expect the use of `factorial` on the RHS to be the same `factorial` as the one on the LHS, right?

Well in the same way, the following defines `i` and `j` in terms of themselves:

```
ghci> (i,j) = (j,i)
```

Answer (score 3):

The shortest sequence I can think of is this:

```
(i', j') = (i, j)
(i, j) = (j', i')
```

This is of course only valid for GHCi, just like the original sequence. In a normal Haskell module such definitions cannot occur in the same lexical scope.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the properties that GHCi runs in an implicit IO do block, and that variables in do binds are not in scope on their right hand side:

```
(i, j) <- return (j, i)
```

You do however get warnings from -Wname-shadowing, if you enabled it (including via -Wall).